# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Connection::prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop, pdo

I want to create a new database using php oop class, I had Create 2 class the first class to connect to localhost only , and the second class to create a database in this localhost depending on connection class "first class"

```
class Connection 
{
    public $conn;

    function __construct() {
        try {

            $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            die($e->getMessage());

        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
}


class CreateNewDataBase
{
    public $connect;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect = new Connection;

        $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE `startex` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci';
        $query = $this->connect->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();  
        if ($query) echo 'Done Your Database Is Created Successfuly';

    }
}

$newObject= new CreateNewDataBase;
```

The output is

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Connection::prepare()....CreateNewDataBase->__construct() thrown in my
>   file bath

Comment: You cannot return a value from a constructor, but it should still set the `$conn` value, as it's public, you could use `$this->connect->conn->prepare($sql);`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Connection` class does not have a `prepare` method.

The constructor isn't going to return what you have in the `return` statement when you are `new`ing up a new instance of that class. It is for instantiating the object; you are not the caller of the `__construct` method at this moment.

```
$conn = new Connection;
```

This is assigning by reference the new object that is created by using the `new` keyword, regardless of any return statement in the constructor.

You could reach the PDO connection in the `Connection` class from inside `CreateNewDataBase` constructor though:

```
$this->connection->conn
```